# VBScript Parameter not getting matching value from Dictionary

Tags: dictionary, vbscript, asp-classic

Dictionary is not returning matching value of VB script function parameter that I have passed from JavaScript function.

Javascript is passing the prodid value successfully to Vb script function and I also read it in VBscript function but when I try to get value from dictionary it returns nothing.

For example, if I pass prodid=1  and then it will be assigned to ProdcutId but it don't get the matching value from dictionary for ProductId=1.
but I hard coded ProductId="1" then It will return the matching value apple from Dictionary.
When I print ProductId value in GetProdcutName, it shows the correct value "1".

Classic ASP:

```
Public Function GetProductName(prodid)
  Dim ProductId 
  Dim ProductName 
  ProductId = prodid
  Dim dictproduct
  Set dictproduct=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

  dictproduct.add "1","apple"
  dictproduct.add "2","Samsung"
  dictproduct.add "3","Blackberry"

  ProductName =dictproduct.Item(ProductId)
  GetProdcutName =ProductName 
End function
```

JavaScript:

```js
function ProductName()
{
  var prodcutid=document.getElementById('prodcutList').value ;      
  var productname ='<%=GetYodleeProviderCode("' + prodcutid + '")%>';
}
```

Comment: There is a typo in the Function name when you try to return `ProductName` *(which is it `GetProdcutName` or `GetProductName`??)*. Plus the function call `GetYodleeProviderCode()` isn't `GetProductName()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fixing the typos in the code you posted (spelling of Product), forcing `prodid` to string should fix your problem: `ProductId = CStr(prodid)`. This should be equivalent to what you tried when you hardcoded 1 as "1".

```
Public Function GetProductName(p_iProdId)
  Dim sProductId
  Dim sProductName

  sProductId = "P" & Trim(CStr(p_iProdId))

  Dim dictProducts
  Set dictProducts = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

  dictProducts.Add "P1", "apple"
  dictProducts.Add "P2", "Samsung"
  dictProducts.Add "P3", "Blackberry"

  sProductName = dictProducts.Item(sProductId)

  GetProductName = sProductName

End Function
```

Comment: It's still giving same the result. Function is returning nothing if i pass p_iProdId=1 but it returns matching value  while I hardcoded  p_iProdId="1" or any other value.

Comment: Although it is unlikely, perhaps your parameter has spaces in it. I added a `Trim()` around the `CStr`. Your value should be clean by then. Also added `P` prefix to your product codes. That should eliminate any confusion when the Dictionary looks up the key.

Comment: Thanks  Étienne. I trimmed the parameter and a weird thing noticed that parameter has fixed length of 18 characters even after trimming it. I checked the paramter value in calling function its seems passing the correct value.

Comment: I would try `CStr(CInt(prodid))` to try and trim it down to just the number

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you misspelled the function name when assigning the return value (the "c" and "u" were reversed).  It should be:

```
GetProductName = ProductName
```

Comment: and another typo in the javascript part: getElementById('prod**cu**tList')